# Optimize check for a bit-vector being a proper subset of another?

Tags: c++, optimization, x86, sse, bitset

I would like some help optimizing the most computationally intensive function of my program.
Currently, I am finding that the basic (non-SSE) version is significantly faster (up to 3x). I would thus request your help in rectifying this.

The function looks for subsets in unsigned integer vectors, and reports if they exist or not. For your convenience I have included the relevant code snippets only.

First up is the basic variant. It checks to see if `blocks_` is a proper subset of `x.blocks_`.  (Not exactly equal.)  These are bitmaps, aka bit vectors or bitsets.

```
//Check for self comparison
    if (this == &x)
            return false;

//A subset is equal to or smaller.
    if (no_bits_ > x.no_bits_)
            return false;

    int i;

    bool equal = false;

//Pointers should not change.  
    const unsigned int *tptr = blocks_;
    const unsigned int *xptr = x.blocks_;

    
    for (i = 0; i < no_blocks_; i++, tptr++, xptr++) {
            if ((*tptr & *xptr) != *tptr)
                    return false;
            if (*tptr != *xptr)
                    equal = true;
    }

    return equal;
```

Then comes the SSE variant, which alas does not perform according to my expectations. Both of these snippets should look for the same things.

```
    //starting pointers.        
    const __m128i* start = (__m128i*)&blocks_;
    const __m128i* xstart = (__m128i*)&x.blocks_;
    
    __m128i block;
    __m128i xblock;

    //Unsigned ints are 32 bits, meaning 4 can fit in a register.
    for (i = 0; i < no_blocks_; i+=4) {

            block = _mm_load_si128(start + i);
            xblock = _mm_load_si128(xstart + i);

                    //Equivalent to  (block & xblock) != block
                    if (_mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi32(_mm_and_si128(block, xblock), block)) != 0xffff)
                            return false;

                    //Equivalent to block != xblock
                    if (_mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpeq_epi32(block, xblock)) != 0xffff)
                            equal = true;
    }
    return equal;
```

Do you have any suggestions as to how I may improve upon the performance of the SSE version? Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a case where optimization should be done elsewhere?

I have not yet added in the leftover calculations for `no_blocks_ % 4 != 0`, but there is little purpose in doing so until the performance increases, and it would only clutter up the code at this point.

Comment: Have you actually looked at what the compiler generates for the two cases. I've found that GCC/G++ generates pretty decent SSE code in the first place (and it's better at avoiding "register dependencies" that us humans tend to come up with at times).

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/4-329

Comment: Isn't `equal` named backwards?  It's true if they're *not* equal, so it a clearer name would be `diff` or `differ`.  Presumably the scalar version compiled to a `cmov` or something else branchless to avoid frequent mispredicts when updating `equal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three possibilities I see here.

First, your data might not suit wide comparisons. If there's a high chance that `(*tptr & *xptr) != *tptr` within the first few blocks, the plain C++ version will almost certainly always be faster. In that instance, your SSE will run through more code & data to accomplish the same thing.

Second, your SSE code may be incorrect. It's not totally clear here. If `no_blocks_` is identical between the two samples, then `start + i` is probably having the unwanted behavior of indexing into 128-bit elements, not 32-bit as the first sample.

Third, SSE *really* likes it when instructions can be pipelined, and this is such a short loop that you might not be getting that. You can reduce branching significantly here by processing more than one SSE block at once.

Here's a quick untested shot at processing 2 SSE blocks at once. Note I've removed the `block != xblock` branch entirely by keeping the state outside of the loop and only testing at the end. In total, this moves things from 1.3 branches per `int` to 0.25.

```
bool equal(unsigned const *a, unsigned const *b, unsigned count)
{
    __m128i eq1 = _mm_setzero_si128();
    __m128i eq2 = _mm_setzero_si128();

    for (unsigned i = 0; i != count; i += 8)
    {
        __m128i xa1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(a + i));
        __m128i xb1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(b + i));

        eq1 = _mm_or_si128(eq1, _mm_xor_si128(xa1, xb1));
        xa1 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(xa1, _mm_and_si128(xa1, xb1));

        __m128i xa2 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(a + i + 4));
        __m128i xb2 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(b + i + 4));

        eq2 = _mm_or_si128(eq2, _mm_xor_si128(xa2, xb2));
        xa2 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(xa2, _mm_and_si128(xa2, xb2));

        if (_mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_packs_epi32(xa1, xa2)) != 0xFFFF)
            return false;
    }

    return _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_or_si128(eq1, eq2)) != 0;
}
```

If you've got enough data and a low probability of failure within the first few SSE blocks, something like this should be at least somewhat faster than your SSE.

Comment: I have attempted both solutions now. Unfortunately, it does not appear to speed anything up, rather it takes even longer. Correcting the indexing did however help somewhat. Thank you for your time and effort nonetheless, as I have come out of this smarter and with hopefully better branch awareness.

Comment: What data are you feeding it? I'm beginning to suspect you're breaking out of the loop really early.

Comment: Yes, that turned out to be the case. After checking iterations, most calls completed the loop. However, what I did not test before; of the ones that did complete the loop, the vast majority were small (checked at `no_blocks_ <= 16`). In response, I shall attempt to either enforce larger vectors or move the vectors to a static size, and then use vectors of vectors that I can hopefully pipeline in a smart way.

Comment: If there's a high chance that `(*tptr & *xptr) != *tptr` within the first few blocks, that's ok for SIMD.  It means no branch mispredicts most of the time, just a usually-correct prediction of returning false on the first pass through the loop.  x86 SIMD is very tightly coupled to the integer part of the core; it doesn't need large problems to be good, especially when you know your data is aligned.  Unlike a strcmp or something, this doesn't even have to figure out where the mismatch happened, just true or false, so it barely has extra overhead vs. scalar.

Comment: You don't need `_mm_packs_epi32`, you could use another `and`.  If either vector isn't all-ones, you'll get some zero elements in the result.  Other than that, yeah looks good; unrolling by 2 is reasonable to amortize the pmovmsk/cmp.  And accumulating diffs with `xor` / `or` is good to avoid branching inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that your problem is a memory bandwidth bounded problem:
Asymptotic you need about 2 operation for processing a pair of integer in memory scanned. There is not enough arithmetic complexity to get advantage of use more arithmetic throughput from CPU SSE instructions. In fact you CPU pass lot of time waiting for data transfers.
But using SSE instructions in your case induce a overall of instructions and resulting code is not well optimized by compiler.

There are some alternatives strategies to improve performance in bandwidth bounded problem:

- Multi-thread hide access memory by concurrent arithmetic
  operations in hyper-threading context.
- Fine tuning of size of data load at time improve memory bandwidth.
- Improve the pipe-line continuity by adding supplementary independents operations in a loop (scan two different sets of data at each step in your "for" loop)
- Keep more data in cache or in registers (some iterations of your code may be need the same set of data many times)

Comment: Modern CPUs have a lot more memory bandwidth than they used to.  2 ints per clock cycle is not a problem, especially if the bit-vectors are small and are still hot in L1d or L2 cache.  The more likely problem with the manually-vectorized code in the question is branch mispredicts.